# convex approximation for a non convex function

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization, convexity

Consider the function

$f\left( {{x_1},...,{x_M},{y_1},...,{y_N}} \right) = \left( {\sum\limits_{j = 1}^M {{\alpha _j}{x_j}} } \right)\left( {{e^{ - \sum\limits_{i = 1}^N {{\beta _i}{y_i}} }}} \right)$

where ${\alpha _j} \ge 0,{\beta _i} \ge 0$ are given constants.  This function is non-convex since the Hessian matrix is not positive semi-definite. How can I obtain a good lower or upper convex approximation for this function?